# output with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that runs within the body. How can I make it output directly after itself. Similar to echo in php.

e.g.

```
    <div id="text">Text</div>

    <div id="someotherdiv">
    The text above says 
    <script>
    $('#text').html().echo?;
    </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for `document.write`, like this:

```
document.write($('#text').html());
```

**EDIT**: `document.write` will only work while the page is loading (as opposed to in an event handler or timer).
To append content later, use jQuery:

```
$('#someotherdiv').append($('#text').html());
```

Comment: I tried this and it replaced the entire page. I want it to output next to the </script> tag... please help

Comment: This will only work while the page is still loading.  If not, you should use jQuery's `after` (or similar) method to insert the element or HTML into the DOM.